# Convergence of the derivative of a power series on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm wondering if the series $\sum a_nx^n$ converges at $x=R$, the radius of convergence, can we conclude that it's derivative also converges when x=R ?

Answer (score 3):

No, we cannot. The power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2}$ has radius of convergence $1$ and it converges on $[-1,1]$. But the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}n$ only converges on $[-1,1)$; it diverges when $x=1$.